# Is there a way to simulate mobile connectivity without credit on an AVD?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I am trying to simulate this scenario. I have tried setting the signal strength to none and turning off Wifi but the app will connect anyway to the remote database. Is this a bug in the simulator or is it the correct behavior?

Comment: Your title and question aren't related. Which one is it? Why not just turn on Airplane Mode?

Comment: Because that would mean completely disabling the connectivity. What I a trying to do is to foresee my employees that will not use my app by purposely not loading credit into their phones. Does it make sense?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If they don't pay for a plan your app isn't going to magically give them free data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Android Emulator to fake complicated network situations. It sounds like you want "Data status" to be set to "Unregistered (off)" or "Denied", since you want to be on a mobile network but not have data transfer.

If you've already tried this, check that your app isn't just showing cached data by performing a clean install.

[image]